# CSS Flexbox is Duplicating divs

Tags: html, css

I use CSS flex box to center a img inside of a div element. But After I gave the display:flex; property to my container Google chrome web browser shows two div element next to each other.

[image: Output]

This is my code.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  /* margin: 20px; */
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}

div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 200px;
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="picture.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I use dev tools to inspect this.I delete the duplicated div. But after I save the code it start to show up again. Every time I save the code it comes back. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: My guess is that div is being appended by a script in the page, possibly the `live-server` one directly above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ray says, something must be injecting the extra `div`. (It is not `live-server`, as it does not inject a `div`, it only reloads the page and handles CSS refreshes.)
It is probably a injected by a browser extension and normally hidden.
Check the styles on the extra `div`. If there are any styles that are not from you, they must have come from somewhere; you can check their source (filename, etc.) and probably track down the culprit.

As your styling uses just an element selector, it applies to all `div`s on the page, including the extra injected one.
Aside: Using bare element selectors for anything but base styles (CSS reset, base typography, etc.) is usually a bad idea, especially on generic elements like `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to classify the div which is belongs to your borders. You should also edit your css file accordingly. So those values ​​will not be valid for every div. The second visible borders can be any div that the live server automatically assigns. I hope I was able to convey my thoughts. For example you can write like this

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  /* margin: 20px; */
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}

.borders {
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 200px;
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="borders">
  <img src="picture.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a problem in your CSS code. Try this instead.

Basically you just need to add `align-items: center;` to your div

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  /* margin: 20px; */
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}

div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 200px;
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* add this line to center img vertically */
}
```

[This is the result](https://prnt.sc/S1yXdZokJBbP)